# Extracting daypart Items for the Python List

Tags: python, list

how do I extract the items from the 'daypart' item in the list below.

```
forecast_data = requests.get(fiveDayForecastUrl)
forecast_dictionary = forecast_data.json()
json_list = list(forecast_dictionary.items())
print(any('cloudCover' in inner_list for inner_list in forecast_dictionary['daypart']))
print(json_list)
```

Result of json_list is below.

```
[('calendarDayTemperatureMax', [28, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30]), ('calendarDayTemperatureMin', [15, 16, 18, 17, 16, 15]), ('dayOfWeek', ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']), ('expirationTimeUtc', [1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025]), ('moonPhase', ['First Quarter', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous']), ('moonPhaseCode', ['FQ', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG']), ('moonPhaseDay', [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]), ('moonriseTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T12:30:04+0200', '2022-02-09T13:24:48+0200', '2022-02-10T14:18:50+0200', '2022-02-11T15:13:16+0200', '2022-02-12T16:05:40+0200', '2022-02-13T16:55:40+0200']), ('moonriseTimeUtc', [1644316204, 1644405888, 1644495530, 1644585196, 1644674740, 1644764140]), ('moonsetTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T23:39:38+0200', '', '2022-02-10T00:16:37+0200', '2022-02-11T00:58:13+0200', '2022-02-12T01:44:21+0200', '2022-02-13T02:34:17+0200']), ('moonsetTimeUtc', [1644356378, None, 1644444997, 1644533893, 1644623061, 1644712457]), ('narrative', ['Partly cloudy. Low 16C.', 'Plenty of sun. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 17 to 19C.', 'Thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. Highs 26 to 28C and lows 16 to 18C.', 'Partly cloudy. Highs 27 to 29C and lows 15 to 17C.', 'Mostly sunny. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 14 to 16C.', 'Sunny. Highs 29 to 31C and lows 15 to 17C.']), ('qpf', [0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), ('qpfSnow', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), ('sunriseTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T05:48:01+0200', '2022-02-09T05:48:44+0200', '2022-02-10T05:49:25+0200', '2022-02-11T05:50:07+0200', '2022-02-12T05:50:48+0200', '2022-02-13T05:51:28+0200']), ('sunriseTimeUtc', [1644292081, 1644378524, 1644464965, 1644551407, 1644637848, 1644724288]), ('sunsetTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T18:54:58+0200', '2022-02-09T18:54:18+0200', '2022-02-10T18:53:38+0200', '2022-02-11T18:52:56+0200', '2022-02-12T18:52:13+0200', '2022-02-13T18:51:30+0200']), ('sunsetTimeUtc', [1644339298, 1644425658, 1644512018, 1644598376, 1644684733, 1644771090]), ('temperatureMax', [None, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30]), ('temperatureMin', [16, 18, 17, 16, 15, 16]), ('validTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-09T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-10T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-11T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-12T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-13T07:00:00+0200']), ('validTimeUtc', [1644296400, 1644382800, 1644469200, 1644555600, 1644642000, 1644728400]), ('daypart', [{'cloudCover': [None, 29, 33, 29, 40, 40, 37, 40, 25, 20, 12, 18], 'dayOrNight': [None, 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N'], 'daypartName': [None, 'Tonight', 'Tomorrow', 'Tomorrow night', 'Thursday', 'Thursday night', 'Friday', 'Friday night', 'Saturday', 'Saturday night', 'Sunday', 'Sunday night'], 'iconCode': [None, 29, 34, 29, 38, 29, 30, 29, 34, 33, 32, 33], 'iconCodeExtend': [None, 2900, 3400, 2900, 7203, 2900, 3000, 2900, 3400, 3300, 3200, 3300], 'narrative': [None, 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds light and variable.', 'Except for a few afternoon clouds, mainly sunny. High 29C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 18C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy early. Scattered thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. High 27C. Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 50%.', 'A few clouds. Low 17C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy skies. High 28C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. High 29C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. Low around 15C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Sunny. High near 30C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Mostly clear. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'], 'precipChance': [None, 8, 22, 8, 50, 18, 24, 18, 4, 2, 2, 3], 'precipType': [None, 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain'], 'qpf': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'qpfSnow': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'qualifierCode': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'qualifierPhrase': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'relativeHumidity': [None, 79, 50, 65, 55, 76, 51, 58, 37, 54, 38, 54], 'snowRange': [None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 'temperature': [None, 16, 29, 18, 27, 17, 28, 16, 29, 15, 30, 16], 'temperatureHeatIndex': [None, 19, 28, 24, 27, 22, 27, 23, 28, 23, 29, 24], 'temperatureWindChill': [None, 17, 19, 18, 20, 17, 19, 16, 17, 15, 17, 17], 'thunderCategory': [None, 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'Thunder expected', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder'], 'thunderIndex': [None, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'uvDescription': [None, 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low'], 'uvIndex': [None, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0], 'windDirection': [None, 140, 288, 126, 30, 95, 38, 86, 53, 81, 41, 83], 'windDirectionCardinal': [None, 'SE', 'WNW', 'SE', 'NNE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E'], 'windPhrase': [None, 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'], 'windSpeed': [None, 9, 11, 10, 16, 9, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 10], 'wxPhraseLong': [None, 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Partly Cloudy', 'PM Thunderstorms', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Mostly Clear', 'Sunny', 'Mostly Clear'], 'wxPhraseShort': [None, 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'P Cloudy', 'PM T-Storms', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'M Clear', 'Sunny', 'M Clear']}])]
```

Comment: you can probably work directly with `forecast_dictionary` to get the results you seek. Rather than posting what you are currently getting for `json_list` maybe post `forecast_dictionary` as I think that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `json_list` you provided, with a little of manual formatting :

```py
json_list = [
    ('calendarDayTemperatureMax', [28, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30]),
    ('calendarDayTemperatureMin', [15, 16, 18, 17, 16, 15]),
    ('dayOfWeek', ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']),
    ('expirationTimeUtc', [1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025]),
    ('moonPhase', ['First Quarter', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous']),
    ('moonPhaseCode', ['FQ', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG']),
    ('moonPhaseDay', [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]),
    ('moonriseTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T12:30:04+0200', '2022-02-09T13:24:48+0200', '2022-02-10T14:18:50+0200', '2022-02-11T15:13:16+0200', '2022-02-12T16:05:40+0200', '2022-02-13T16:55:40+0200']),
    ('moonriseTimeUtc', [1644316204, 1644405888, 1644495530, 1644585196, 1644674740, 1644764140]),
    ('moonsetTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T23:39:38+0200', '', '2022-02-10T00:16:37+0200', '2022-02-11T00:58:13+0200', '2022-02-12T01:44:21+0200', '2022-02-13T02:34:17+0200']),
    ('moonsetTimeUtc', [1644356378, None, 1644444997, 1644533893, 1644623061, 1644712457]),
    ('narrative', ['Partly cloudy. Low 16C.', 'Plenty of sun. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 17 to 19C.', 'Thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. Highs 26 to 28C and lows 16 to 18C.', 'Partly cloudy. Highs 27 to 29C and lows 15 to 17C.', 'Mostly sunny. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 14 to 16C.', 'Sunny. Highs 29 to 31C and lows 15 to 17C.']),
    ('qpf', [0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
    ('qpfSnow', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
    ('sunriseTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T05:48:01+0200', '2022-02-09T05:48:44+0200', '2022-02-10T05:49:25+0200', '2022-02-11T05:50:07+0200', '2022-02-12T05:50:48+0200', '2022-02-13T05:51:28+0200']),
    ('sunriseTimeUtc', [1644292081, 1644378524, 1644464965, 1644551407, 1644637848, 1644724288]),
    ('sunsetTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T18:54:58+0200', '2022-02-09T18:54:18+0200', '2022-02-10T18:53:38+0200', '2022-02-11T18:52:56+0200', '2022-02-12T18:52:13+0200', '2022-02-13T18:51:30+0200']),
    ('sunsetTimeUtc', [1644339298, 1644425658, 1644512018, 1644598376, 1644684733, 1644771090]),
    ('temperatureMax', [None, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30]),
    ('temperatureMin', [16, 18, 17, 16, 15, 16]),
    ('validTimeLocal', ['2022-02-08T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-09T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-10T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-11T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-12T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-13T07:00:00+0200']),
    ('validTimeUtc', [1644296400, 1644382800, 1644469200, 1644555600, 1644642000, 1644728400]),
    ('daypart', [{'cloudCover': [None, 29, 33, 29, 40, 40, 37, 40, 25, 20, 12, 18],
                  'dayOrNight': [None, 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N'],
                  'daypartName': [None, 'Tonight', 'Tomorrow', 'Tomorrow night', 'Thursday', 'Thursday night', 'Friday', 'Friday night', 'Saturday', 'Saturday night', 'Sunday', 'Sunday night'],
                  'iconCode': [None, 29, 34, 29, 38, 29, 30, 29, 34, 33, 32, 33],
                  'iconCodeExtend': [None, 2900, 3400, 2900, 7203, 2900, 3000, 2900, 3400, 3300, 3200, 3300],
                  'narrative': [None, 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds light and variable.', 'Except for a few afternoon clouds, mainly sunny. High 29C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 18C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy early. Scattered thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. High 27C. Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 50%.', 'A few clouds. Low 17C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy skies. High 28C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. High 29C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. Low around 15C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Sunny. High near 30C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Mostly clear. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'],
                  'precipChance': [None, 8, 22, 8, 50, 18, 24, 18, 4, 2, 2, 3],
                  'precipType': [None, 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain'],
                  'qpf': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  'qpfSnow': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  'qualifierCode': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                  'qualifierPhrase': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                  'relativeHumidity': [None, 79, 50, 65, 55, 76, 51, 58, 37, 54, 38, 54],
                  'snowRange': [None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                  'temperature': [None, 16, 29, 18, 27, 17, 28, 16, 29, 15, 30, 16],
                  'temperatureHeatIndex': [None, 19, 28, 24, 27, 22, 27, 23, 28, 23, 29, 24],
                  'temperatureWindChill': [None, 17, 19, 18, 20, 17, 19, 16, 17, 15, 17, 17],
                  'thunderCategory': [None, 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'Thunder expected', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder'],
                  'thunderIndex': [None, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'uvDescription': [None, 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low'],
                  'uvIndex': [None, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0],
                  'windDirection': [None, 140, 288, 126, 30, 95, 38, 86, 53, 81, 41, 83],
                  'windDirectionCardinal': [None, 'SE', 'WNW', 'SE', 'NNE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E'],
                  'windPhrase': [None, 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'],
                  'windSpeed': [None, 9, 11, 10, 16, 9, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 10],
                  'wxPhraseLong': [None, 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Partly Cloudy', 'PM Thunderstorms', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Mostly Clear', 'Sunny', 'Mostly Clear'],
                  'wxPhraseShort': [None, 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'P Cloudy', 'PM T-Storms', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'M Clear', 'Sunny', 'M Clear']
                  }]
     )
]
```

Because you converted to a `list` the result of `forecast_dictionary.items()`, it means that here is the dictionary you started with :

```py
forecast_dictionary = dict(json_list)
# or, more explicitly :
forecast_dictionary = {
    'calendarDayTemperatureMax': [28, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    'calendarDayTemperatureMin': [15, 16, 18, 17, 16, 15],
    'dayOfWeek': ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    'expirationTimeUtc': [1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025, 1644346025],
    'moonPhase': ['First Quarter', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'Waxing Gibbous'],
    'moonPhaseCode': ['FQ', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG', 'WXG'],
    'moonPhaseDay': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11],
    'moonriseTimeLocal': ['2022-02-08T12:30:04+0200', '2022-02-09T13:24:48+0200', '2022-02-10T14:18:50+0200', '2022-02-11T15:13:16+0200', '2022-02-12T16:05:40+0200', '2022-02-13T16:55:40+0200'],
    'moonriseTimeUtc': [1644316204, 1644405888, 1644495530, 1644585196, 1644674740, 1644764140],
    'moonsetTimeLocal': ['2022-02-08T23:39:38+0200', '', '2022-02-10T00:16:37+0200', '2022-02-11T00:58:13+0200', '2022-02-12T01:44:21+0200', '2022-02-13T02:34:17+0200'],
    'moonsetTimeUtc': [1644356378, None, 1644444997, 1644533893, 1644623061, 1644712457],
    'narrative': ['Partly cloudy. Low 16C.', 'Plenty of sun. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 17 to 19C.', 'Thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. Highs 26 to 28C and lows 16 to 18C.', 'Partly cloudy. Highs 27 to 29C and lows 15 to 17C.', 'Mostly sunny. Highs 28 to 30C and lows 14 to 16C.', 'Sunny. Highs 29 to 31C and lows 15 to 17C.'],
    'qpf': [0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'qpfSnow': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'sunriseTimeLocal': ['2022-02-08T05:48:01+0200', '2022-02-09T05:48:44+0200', '2022-02-10T05:49:25+0200', '2022-02-11T05:50:07+0200', '2022-02-12T05:50:48+0200', '2022-02-13T05:51:28+0200'],
    'sunriseTimeUtc': [1644292081, 1644378524, 1644464965, 1644551407, 1644637848, 1644724288],
    'sunsetTimeLocal': ['2022-02-08T18:54:58+0200', '2022-02-09T18:54:18+0200', '2022-02-10T18:53:38+0200', '2022-02-11T18:52:56+0200', '2022-02-12T18:52:13+0200', '2022-02-13T18:51:30+0200'],
    'sunsetTimeUtc': [1644339298, 1644425658, 1644512018, 1644598376, 1644684733, 1644771090],
    'temperatureMax': [None, 29, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    'temperatureMin': [16, 18, 17, 16, 15, 16],
    'validTimeLocal': ['2022-02-08T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-09T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-10T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-11T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-12T07:00:00+0200', '2022-02-13T07:00:00+0200'],
    'validTimeUtc': [1644296400, 1644382800, 1644469200, 1644555600, 1644642000, 1644728400],
    'daypart': [{'cloudCover': [None, 29, 33, 29, 40, 40, 37, 40, 25, 20, 12, 18],
                 'dayOrNight': [None, 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'N'],
                 'daypartName': [None, 'Tonight', 'Tomorrow', 'Tomorrow night', 'Thursday', 'Thursday night', 'Friday', 'Friday night', 'Saturday', 'Saturday night', 'Sunday', 'Sunday night'],
                 'iconCode': [None, 29, 34, 29, 38, 29, 30, 29, 34, 33, 32, 33],
                 'iconCodeExtend': [None, 2900, 3400, 2900, 7203, 2900, 3000, 2900, 3400, 3300, 3200, 3300],
                 'narrative': [None, 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds light and variable.', 'Except for a few afternoon clouds, mainly sunny. High 29C. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 18C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy early. Scattered thunderstorms developing in the afternoon. High 27C. Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 50%.', 'A few clouds. Low 17C. Winds light and variable.', 'Partly cloudy skies. High 28C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Partly cloudy. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. High 29C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'A few clouds from time to time. Low around 15C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Sunny. High near 30C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Mostly clear. Low 16C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'],
                 'precipChance': [None, 8, 22, 8, 50, 18, 24, 18, 4, 2, 2, 3],
                 'precipType': [None, 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'rain'],
                 'qpf': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 'qpfSnow': [None, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 'qualifierCode': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 'qualifierPhrase': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 'relativeHumidity': [None, 79, 50, 65, 55, 76, 51, 58, 37, 54, 38, 54],
                 'snowRange': [None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                 'temperature': [None, 16, 29, 18, 27, 17, 28, 16, 29, 15, 30, 16],
                 'temperatureHeatIndex': [None, 19, 28, 24, 27, 22, 27, 23, 28, 23, 29, 24],
                 'temperatureWindChill': [None, 17, 19, 18, 20, 17, 19, 16, 17, 15, 17, 17],
                 'thunderCategory': [None, 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'Thunder expected', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder', 'No thunder'],
                 'thunderIndex': [None, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 'uvDescription': [None, 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low', 'Extreme', 'Low'],
                 'uvIndex': [None, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0],
                 'windDirection': [None, 140, 288, 126, 30, 95, 38, 86, 53, 81, 41, 83],
                 'windDirectionCardinal': [None, 'SE', 'WNW', 'SE', 'NNE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E', 'NE', 'E'],
                 'windPhrase': [None, 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NNE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds light and variable.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h.', 'Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.'],
                 'windSpeed': [None, 9, 11, 10, 16, 9, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 10],
                 'wxPhraseLong': [None, 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Partly Cloudy', 'PM Thunderstorms', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Partly Cloudy', 'Mostly Sunny', 'Mostly Clear', 'Sunny', 'Mostly Clear'],
                 'wxPhraseShort': [None, 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'P Cloudy', 'PM T-Storms', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'P Cloudy', 'M Sunny', 'M Clear', 'Sunny', 'M Clear']
                 }]
}
```

If you want to get the `daypart` item from the dictionary, then it is simply :

```py
daypart_item = forecast_dictionary["daypart"]
print(json.dumps(daypart_item))
```

```json
[{"cloudCover": [null, 29, 33, 29, 40, 40, 37, 40, 25, 20, 12, 18], "dayOrNight": ... }]
```